# Select com campos sem valores

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo um `SELECT` onde junto duas tabelas: uma tabela de saldo de produtos em estoque e outra tabela com pedido de compras.

Estou fazendo uma comparação entre saldo de produtos em estoque e saldo em pedidos de compras, só que da forma que estou fazendo, o `SELECT` está trazendo somente produtos que tem saldo de pedido de compra em aberto no sistema.

Preciso que o `SELECT` traga não somente os produtos que tenham saldo em pedido de compras, como também todos os produtos da tabela produtos independente se tem pedido de compras colocado ou não. Os produtos que não tiver pedido de compras colocado e `SELECT` traz o valor 0 na coluna.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT SB1.B1_DESC            AS PRODUTO
        ,   SUM(SB8.B8_SALDO)               AS SALDO
        ,   (SC7.C7_QUANT - SC7.C7_QUJE)    AS [SALDO DE COMPRAS]
        ,   SC7.C7_NUM                      AS PEDIDO
        ,   SB1.B1_EMIN                     AS [SALDO MINIMO EM ESTOQUE]
FROM        SB1010 AS SB1
INNER JOIN  SB8010 AS SB8 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SB8.B8_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
INNER JOIN  SC7010 AS SC7 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SC7.C7_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
WHERE       ISB8.B8_LOCAL   =  '01'
        AND SC7.C7_ENCER    <> 'E'
        AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_  =  ''
        AND SB8.D_E_L_E_T_  =  ''
        AND SC7.D_E_L_E_T_  =  ''
GROUP BY    SB1.B1_DESC
        ,   SB1.B1_EMIN
        ,   SC7.C7_QUANT
        ,   SC7.C7_QUJE
        ,   SC7.C7_NUM
```

**OBS**: Nesse `SELECT` tenho um filtro `SC7.C7_ENCER` que significa os pedidos de compras já finalizados.

Comment: Ajudaria se você comentasse o que é cada coluna e identificar cada tabela, pois os nomes não são nada legíveis.

Comment: SB1 tabela de produtos, SB8 tabela de saldo de produtos, SC7 tabela de pedido de compras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deve trocar os `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`, evitando assim que o código da tabela `SB1` exista obrigatoriamente nas outras duas tabelas.

Um aspeto que poderá ter impacto é o facto de não validar os `NULL` na cláusula `WHERE`, que quase de certeza impede a obtenção de outro resultado.

Penso que assim deverá funcionar:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT SB1.B1_DESC                    AS PRODUTO
        ,   SUM(ISNULL(SB8.B8_SALDO, 0))            AS SALDO
        ,   ISNULL((SC7.C7_QUANT - SC7.C7_QUJE, 0)) AS [SALDO DE COMPRAS]
            -- não sei o tipo da coluna, por isso coloquei "0"
            -- se for VARCHAR colocar '' ou outro valor por omissão em caso de NULL
        ,   ISNULL(SC7.C7_NUM, 0)                   AS PEDIDO
        ,   ISNULL(SB1.B1_EMIN, 0)                  AS [SALDO MINIMO EM ESTOQUE]
FROM        SB1010 AS SB1
LEFT JOIN   SB8010 AS SB8 (NOLOCK) ON SB8.B8_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
LEFT JOIN   SC7010 AS SC7 (NOLOCK) ON SC7.C7_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
WHERE       ISNULL(SB8.B8_LOCAL, '')    =  '01'
        AND ISNULL(SC7.C7_ENCER, '')    <> 'E'
        AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_              =  ''
        AND ISNULL(SB8.D_E_L_E_T_, '')  =  ''
        AND ISNULL(SC7.D_E_L_E_T_, '')  =  ''
GROUP BY    SB1.B1_DESC
        ,   SB1.B1_EMIN
        ,   ISNULL(SC7.C7_QUANT, 0)
        ,   ISNULL(SC7.C7_QUJE, 0)
        ,   ISNULL(SC7.C7_NUM, 0)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda deu certinho aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Troque INNER JOIN para LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SB1.B1_DESC       AS PRODUTO,
SUM(SB8.B8_SALDO) AS SALDO,
(SC7.C7_QUANT - SC7.C7_QUJE) AS [SALDO DE COMPRAS],
SC7.C7_NUM AS PEDIDO,
SB1.B1_EMIN AS [SALDO MINIMO EM ESTOQUE]
FROM SB1010 AS SB1
LEFT JOIN SB8010 AS SB8 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SB8.B8_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
LEFT JOIN SC7010 AS SC7 WITH(NOLOCK) ON SC7.C7_PRODUTO = SB1.B1_COD
WHERE SB8.B8_LOCAL = '01'
AND SC7.C7_ENCER <> 'E'
AND SB1.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
AND SB8.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
AND SC7.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
GROUP BY SB1.B1_DESC, SB1.B1_EMIN, SC7.C7_QUANT, SC7.C7_QUJE, SC7.C7_NUM
```

Comment: obrigado pela atenção mas ja tentei com join e não muda o resultado.